# How to modify comment reply form?

Tags: ajax, comments

I've installed the [Ajax comments](https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_comments) module.

I am not able to modify comment form. I want to modify the comment form which one is coming when click reply link.

**Note**: When I click add new comment the form will show subject, name, comment field. In reply option also showing same form. But I don't want subject and name in reply comment form.

Comment: More elaboration is needed on the specific problem UR having.

Comment: @Benia when i click add new comment the form will show subject,name, comment field. in reply option also showing same form. but i don't want subject and name in reply comment form.

Comment: you can override comment form tpl file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the reply form and the comment form are the same forms (form_id: comment_node_NODE_TYPE_form), you shouldn't think they are different forms.

Second, you would need some custom coding in your own module, that would look like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function yourmodule_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
```

OR, even more specific to comments on article nodes (you can replace article with page, blog, YOUR_CUSTOM_CONTENT_TYPE)

```
function yourmodule_form_comment_node_article_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form_state['comment'])) {
    $comment = $form_state['comment'];
    // if this is a reply, hide the two fields
    if($comment->pid > 0) {
      $form['subject']['#access'] = FALSE;
      $form['author']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Using D8 you can check if the form is a reply with : $is_reply = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity()->hasParentComment();

Answer (score 1):

I know the pain. I already face the issue.

Just copy the below two functions in an new module and rename the first function name to module name.

***Explanation:***

Here we just need to remove ' + .indented' in line no 602 & 607. So copy entire `function ajax_comments_reply` code on to new module This does the trick

Use Menu alter function to modify page callback

```
function <MODULE_NAME>_menu_alter(&$items) {
// Altering Comment reply function to load form next to reply button
  $items['ajax_comment/reply/%node']['page callback'] = 'ajax_comments_reply_alter';

}
```

Remove 'indent' when rendering commands `ajax_command_append`.

```
 /**
 * Callback for clicking "reply".
 * Note: $pid is an optional parameter. This functionality is utilized by the
 * "Add new comment" link on pages where there is no default comment form
 * (comment_form_location is COMMENT_FORM_SEPARATE_PAGE)
 */
function ajax_comments_reply_alter($node, $pid = 0, $flag = 0) {
  if (!user_access('post comments')) {
    return MENU_ACCESS_DENIED;
  }

  // If there is a pid this is a reply to a comment.
  if (!empty($pid)) {
    if (!user_access('access comments')) {
      return MENU_ACCESS_DENIED;
    }

    // Make sure the comment is valid and published.
    if (!($comments = comment_load_multiple(array($pid), array('status' => COMMENT_PUBLISHED)))) {
      return MENU_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    $comment = $comments[$pid];

    // Make sure the comment belongs to this node.
    if ($comment->nid != $node->nid) {
      return MENU_NOT_FOUND;
    }
  }

  if ((!user_is_anonymous() || (user_is_anonymous() && variable_get('cache', 0) != 0))) {
    // Authenticated user or anonymous and page cache is enabled
    $key = _ajax_comments_cache_key($node->nid, $pid);
    if ($cache = cache_get($key)) {
      // Get form from cache
      $form_build = $cache->data;
    }
    else {
      // Build form and Save to cache*/
      $form_build = drupal_get_form("comment_node_{$node->type}_form", (object) array('nid' => $node->nid, 'pid' => $pid), array('flag' => $flag));
      cache_set($key, $form_build, 'cache', time() + 360);
    }
  }
  else {
    // Anonymous and page cache is disabled
    $form_build = drupal_get_form("comment_node_{$node->type}_form", (object) array('nid' => $node->nid, 'pid' => $pid), array('flag' => $flag));
  }

  $form = trim(drupal_render($form_build));

  if (variable_get('ajax_comments_reply_autoclose') && !empty($pid)) {
    $commands[] = ajax_command_remove('.ajax-comments-form-reply');
    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('.ajax-comments-reply', 'show');
  }

  // Add the new form.
  if (!empty($pid)) {
    $mode = variable_get('comment_default_mode_' . $node->type, COMMENT_MODE_THREADED);
    if (empty($mode)) {
      $commands[] = ajax_command_after('.comment-wrapper-' . $pid, $form);
    }
    else {
      // Add div with class "indented" if they are not exist
      $commands[] = array('command' => 'ajaxCommentsAddDummyDivAfter', 'selector' => '.comment-wrapper-' . $pid, 'class' => 'indented');
      // Check sort by comment_goodness.
      if (_ajax_comments_get_comment_sort_order($node) == 1) {
        // Newer first.
        $commands[] = ajax_command_append('.comment-wrapper-' . $pid, $form);
      }
      else {
        // Older first.
        $commands[] = ajax_command_prepend('.comment-wrapper-' . $pid, $form);
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    // Check Views Add form
    if (!empty($flag)) {
      $commands[] = ajax_command_after('.views-comment-wrapper-nid-' . $node->nid . ' > .ajax-comment-wrapper:last', $form);
    }
    else {
      // Check sort by comment_goodness.
      if (_ajax_comments_get_comment_sort_order($node) == 1) {
        // Older first. Append comment to last wrapper.
        $commands[] = ajax_command_after('.comment-wrapper-nid-' . $node->nid . ' > .ajax-comment-wrapper:last', $form);
      }
      else {
        // Newer first. Append comment to top.
        $commands[] = ajax_command_before('.comment-wrapper-nid-' . $node->nid . '> .ajax-comment-wrapper:first', $form);
      }
    }
  }

  // Hide reply to comment link
  $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('.ajax-comments-reply-' . $node->nid . '-' . $pid, 'hide');

  if (!variable_get('ajax_comments_disable_scroll', 0)) {
    $commands[] = array('command' => 'ajaxCommentsScrollToElement', 'selector' => '.ajax-comments-reply-form-' . $node->nid . '-' . $pid . '-0');
    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke('.ajax-comments-reply-form-' . $node->nid . '-' . $pid . '-0 .form-textarea' , 'focus');
  }

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}
```

And Dont forgot to clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to modify the comment form. For example you can use **CSS** to hide the elements.

`.comment-wrapper .form-item-name { display: none; }`

OR place the following in your custom module to remove 'Your Name' from the output

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) 
{   
  $form['author']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

or you can override the comment form tpl

Comment: i don't want to change comment form.i just want to alter when user click reply link it will show comment form i want to modify that one.